# Passing Credentials to Kerberos Authentication

Tags: java, spring, kerberos

I've got a simple Spring MVC application that will use Kerberos Authentication when connecting to an external domain (trying to create Atlassian JIRA tickets). Here's my code

```
System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", path + File.separator +  "config/auth.conf");
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", path + File.separator + "config/krb5.conf");

        try {

          LoginContext lc = new LoginContext("CodePlugin");
          lc.login(); // Breaks here at login
```

My configurations are picked up fine but I'm getting the following error message

```
Debug is  true storeKey false useTicketCache true useKeyTab false doNotPrompt false ticketCache is null isInitiator true KeyTab is null refreshKrb5Config is true principal is null tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
Refreshing Kerberos configuration
Acquire TGT from Cache
Principal is null
null credentials from Ticket Cache
        [Krb5LoginModule] authentication failed 
No CallbackHandler available to garner authentication information from the user
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No CallbackHandler available to garner authentication information from the user
```

Here is my auth.conf

```
com.sun.security.jgss.initiate {

 com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required     

 useKeyTab=false     

 storeKey=false    

 debug=true        

 useTicketCache=true

 refreshKrb5Config=true        

 isInitiator=true;

};

CodePlugin {

 com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required     

 useKeyTab=false     

 storeKey=false    

 debug=true        

 useTicketCache=true

 refreshKrb5Config=true        

 isInitiator=true


};
```

and krb5.conf

```
[libdefaults]
 default_realm = MY.DOMAIN.COM
 ticket_lifetime = 36000
 forwardable = true
 default_etypes = asdf asdf asdf
 default_etypes_des = asdf asdf asdf
    default_tkt_enctypes = asdf asdf asdf
    default_tgs_enctypes = asdf asdf asdfcrc
    permitted_enctypes   = asdf asdf asdf

[realms]
    .my.domain.com  = {
        default_domain = MY.DOMAIN.COM
}

[domain_realm]
    my.domain.com = MY.DOMAIN.COM
```

I'm unsure how to go about setting up a CallbackHandler and passing credentials to my LoginContext. Some articles mentioned creating a `login.conf` and passing credentials there which I've tried but I get the same error. Apologies but I'm very new to Kerberos AuthN. Any suggestions or documentation I can refer to?

Thanks much!